# Is it possible to make an array of table rows in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to make a working grocery store website for a school project. One of the tasks was making a product list for management to use, which includes buttons to add, edit, and delete products. Once a product is deleted, it needs to remain removed from view until the user exits and reruns the page. I have all my product info inside a table, with each product having its own table row. Any suggestions?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if(sessionStorage.getItem("arrayString")){
    var retrievedData = sessionStorage.getItem("arrayString");
    var array2 = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
    for(var i = 0; i < array2.length - 1; i++){
      $(array2[i]).remove();
    }
  }
  $("#btnDelete").click( function() {
    $("#tr").remove();
    array.push("#tr");
    var arrayString = JSON.stringify(array);
    if(!sessionStorage.getItem("arrayString")){
      sessionStorage.setItem("arrayString", true);
    }

  });
});
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: `array.push("#tr");` you're only pushing the string "#tr" - is that intentional?   Could you include part of the table HTML?  Note that `id`s must be unique, so make sure you don't have any `<tr id="tr">`

Comment: Most of your code involves sessionStorage... why do you use that, when the assignment seems to suggest that changes should only be maintained until the page is refreshed? Asking for suggestions is too broad for Stack Overflow. Show your work, and where you are stuck with *specifically*.

Comment: @freedomn-m I'm fairly new at html and JavaScript so I didn't know ids had to be unique. My logic was when the delete button would be clicked, it would add that table row into an array. Then I would use session storage to set the item, and when the page is refreshed I would get the array, iterate over it, and remove all the deleted items that are stored in the array.

Comment: If it's a button per row, it's easiest to use DOM navigation.  `$("tr")` (without id #) would select *all* rows.  If IDs weren't unique or you used a class, it would also select all rows.  In the button click, use `this` for the button, so something like:  `$(this).closest("tr").remove()` would remove just the current tr.  If you want to extract any info from it, do so first before you remove it, eg `var rowid = $(this).closest("tr").data("rowid")`